# Bad hour in crontab file

Tags: cron

I am trying to run a scheduled job via crontab in linux mint. For that, I am using the crontab -e command to edit a crontab file with the following information:

```
0 50 * ? * * *    sh test.sh
```

After which I get the error:

```
"/tmp/crontab.XCXmSA/crontab":22: bad hour
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

I tried searching but couldn't find anything that solved the problem. Tried a bunch of different times and still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried '0 50 * ? * *', maybe it accepts 50 as hours

Comment: Tried it now, did not work.

Comment: '50 * * * *' try that, i don't think you need seconds in your cron and other part is wildcard, so it should be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use totally wrong syntax. You add more stars. And questionmark which is not accepted there. Here is the syntax you search:

```
50 * * * *    sh test.sh
```

And as mentioned in comments you cant have 50 as hour definition

And instead of using explicit shell add it in shebang and make the script executable

Comment: weird, I used a cron expression generator that worked in other situations. Anyway, this worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You put 50 as an hour. Hour should be in `0..23` range.

```
# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

Comment: Yes you were right. Somehow the cron expression generator that I used came up with that cron expression. Thanks anyway.